# How to add a large equation in Latex (problem with \right] \left[)

Tags: equations, arrays

I want to add this equation to my letter, but it doesn't fit the page:

```
$$ I_{GRV3}=\int_{\Sigma_{i}}\left[4 \pi S_{i}^{i}-v^{\mid i} v_{\mid i}+\frac{1}{4} h^{i j}\left(\Delta_{i m}^{l} \Delta_{j l}^{m}-\Delta_{i m}^{l} \Delta_{i j}^{m}\right)+ 
\frac{3}{4}\left(K_{i j} K^{i j}-K^{2}\right)-\frac{K}{N} N^{i} \nu_{i i}\right] \sqrt{h} \mathrm{d}^{3} x=0 $$
```

The problem is that I tried to use an array method to separate them, but I get an error cause I'm separating the `\right]` from the `\left[`.

Comment: use `\bigl[...\bigr]`  then you can separate it over lines, better to use `align*` than `array`

Comment: Thanks, It worked very well.

Comment: Off-topic: please replace both instances of `\mid` with `\vert`.